# Property not found error in ebean derived model

Tags: java, hibernate, ebean

I have a very simple Ebean model :

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity extends Model {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  public int id;

  @WhenCreated
  @Column(name = "createdAt")
  public ZonedDateTime createdAt;

  @WhenModified
  @Column(name = "updatedAt")
  public ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "person_id"))
public class PersonEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @Column(name = "address")
  String address;
}
```

But when I tried to run application, I got error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: If you are running in an IDE with enhancement plugin try a Build -> Rebuild Project to recompile and enhance all entity beans. Error - property createdAt not found in [name, address, id] for type class PersonEntity
```

I searched online for ebean tutorial, https://ebean.io/docs/intro/first-entity/mapped-superclass. And I believe that I did same thing as the tutorial.
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: It says there is no column present with the name of createdAt in Person table, can you please cross check the name of column in your PersonEntity and BaseEntity.